# How to get the number of likes of a facebook post using koala gem get_object function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am trying to use koala gem to retrieve the real like numbers of a Facebook post.

In the Facebook graph explore, I have tried:

`5718732097_10151698726822098/likes?summary=1`

according to the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ page.

This query works and  return a hash with a entry:

`"summary": {
    "total_count": 19541
  }`

So, how could I do this query using koala gem. The main problem is that I do not know how to pass the `summary = 1` to the get_object function.

I have tried:

1.`likes = graph.get_object("5718732097_10151698726822098", summary: 1){|data| data['likes']}`

2.`likes = graph.get_object("5718732097_10151698726822098/likes?summary=1")`

neither of them works, any one can help? Thanks a lot!

Can any one help me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this answer by myself:

So I should do

`graph.get_object(your_post_id, fields => "likes.summary(true)")`

The api documentation that Facebook gave is kind of confused me  here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

It says `summary = 1` which should be `summary = true` in rails